# How do i use setInterval for a carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel, setinterval

I'm trying to make my carousel autoplaying by using the setInterval function, but I've been getting no luck.

I tried calling the carousel function in setInterval function at the end, but its not working.. what did i do wrong?

Here is the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-7ph05?file=/src/index.js

Here are my JS code:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prevBtn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".nextBtn");

// Inline callback function
// forEach(function(element, index, array){ ... })
slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {
  slide.style.left = `${index * 100}%`;

  // console.log(slide);
  // console.log(index);
  // console.log(array);
});

let count = 0;
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count++;
  carousel();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count--;
  carousel();
});

function carousel() {
  slides.forEach(function (slide) {
    if (count > slides.length - 1) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      count = slides.length - 1;
    }

    slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${count * 100}%)`;
    // console.log(slides.length);
    // console.log(slide);
    // console.log(count);
  });
}

setInterval(carousel, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be incrementing the `count` variable in `setInterval` nor invoking the `carousel` function like you do, when the next or previous button is pressed.
Update your `setInterval` to increment the counter and invoke the `carousel` function.

```
setInterval(()=>{
count++ //increment the counter
carousel() //call the function
}, 3000);
```

Your index file should then look something like this:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prevBtn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".nextBtn");

// Inline callback function
// forEach(function(element, index, array){ ... })
slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {
  slide.style.left = `${index * 100}%`;

  // console.log(slide);
  // console.log(index);
  // console.log(array);
});

let count = 0;
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count++;
  carousel();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count--;
  carousel();
});

function carousel() {
  slides.forEach(function (slide) {
    if (count > slides.length - 1) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      count = slides.length - 1;
    }

    slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${count * 100}%)`;
    // console.log(slides.length);
    // console.log(slide);
    // console.log(count);
  });
}

setInterval(()=>{
  count++
  carousel()
}, 3000);
```

Comment: oh thanks it works!
i thought invoking the function in setInterval does not need  the ()

Comment: Skipping the `()` would mean that you're only pointing to a function that is supposed to be handled(called) by some other function some other time, more like a callback. But here, in this case, no other function is invoking the `caraousel` and it needs to be called at every interval, hence the paretheses `()` are mandatory.